# Rails 4: Get sum of all subchildren

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models Customer, Invoice, InvoiceItems. Where Customer has_many Invoices, and Invoices has_many InvoiceItems.

One of the attributes of InvoiceItems is "amount". I want to print the total amount of all invoices for each customer. What is the most efficient and elegant way of doing this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it entirely in SQL, you can use:

```
Customer.joins(invoices: :invoice_items).select('customers.id, sum(amount) as total')
  .group('customers.id').each {|ar| puts ar.id, ar.total}
```

You can of course change the `select` and `group` to use something besides `customers.id` if you want.

A hybrid approach would be:

```
Customer.each do |customer|
  total = customer.invoices.inject(0) do |total, invoice|
    total+invoice.invoice_items.sum('amount')
  puts customer.id, total
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this works quite well. However, each Customer has about 100 invoices which in turn have ~20 items each. Therefore, it takes rather long to run this query. Would it be possible to add individual caching for each invoice(invoice items may change)  or at least each customer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really clueless when it comes to Rails caching. You might want to ask a new question specifically focused on that.